# Find the mean value for each group of rows with mask in pandas and define zero the missing values

Tags: python, pandas, mask

I have an ascii file with multiple rows and I want to find the mean value for each 24 rows excluding from the average the values -9999,0. BUT in case a group of values (24rows) include only -9999 or 0 values then define this row as zero (0).

I do the following but when it does not find values in a group of rows gives "" and not zero.

```
df = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\s+',header=None)
 df_mean=df.mask(df.isin([-9999.0, 0])).groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//24).mean()
 df_mean.to_csv(outfile,sep='\t',header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I would just add on a `.fillna(0)` after the `.mean()`. The only reason you'd get a `NaN` from the groupby mean is if the entire group had null values, and so you can safely just fill that with 0 to get your desired logic (0 when you had all 0s or 9999s that you masked to make null)

Comment: It worked!thanks